# Retrieving current version in ARM template for secret

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I got this secret named "StorageConnectionString" that gets inserted in my Key Vault from ARM:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
  "name": "[concat(variables('keyVaultName-v'),'/','StorageConnectionString')]",
  "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
  "properties": {
    "contentType": "text/plain",
    "value": "OmittedStorageConntionString"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', variables('keyVaultName-v'))]"
  ]
}
```

Is there any way that I can reference and get the url of current version (or just version id) of the inserted secret, from ARM? I want to reference it from an environment variable like mentioned here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/simplifying-security-for-serverless-and-web-apps-with-azure-functions-and-app-service/ under the section "Sourcing Application Settings from Key Vault". I want to set an environment setting `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=secret_uri_with_version)` in my Azure Function.

If this isnt possible, is there another way to set the connectionstring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question was my last resort, and just after I posted this, I found the answer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references#reference-syntax (in the documentation) `"[concat('@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=', reference(variables('storageConnectionStringResourceId')).secretUriWithVersion, ')')]"`.

**EDIT**
By following the i mentioned before, you can in fact reference the secret in the ARM template and get the url to the secret with the version included.

Create a secret:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
  "name": "[concat(variables('keyVaultName-v'),'/', variables('queueStorageConnectionStringSecretName-v'))]",
  "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
  "properties": {
    "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('queueStorageName-v'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageAccountResourceId'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
  }
```

And then you can reference it in your functions app

```
    {
      "name": "StorageQueueConnectionString",
      "value": "[concat('@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=', reference(variables('queueStorageConnectionStringSecretNameResourceId-v')).secretUriWithVersion, ')')]"
    }
```

Then, in your function, you can reference `StorageQueueConnectionString` in a binding

```
[Queue("queueName", Connection ="StorageQueueConnectionString")]
            ICollector<string> outputQueueItem
```

In this way, you dont have to reference the connectionstring in environment variables (or code), making your app a bit more secure. This example requires a system assigned (or user assigned) identity between the functions app and the vault. I am currently trying vault out, and I have made some code that can be found here: https://github.com/mslot/Microservices. The code is not beautiful! I am trying a lot of things out related to key vault and bindings between different Azure entities.

EXTERNAL EDIT:

you have to use a full resourceId of the secret:

```
resourceId('sub','rg','Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets','vault_name','secret_name')
```

minimal template to repro:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [],
    "outputs": {
        "collection": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[reference('/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/yyy/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/zzz/secrets/www', '2018-02-14').secretUriWithVersion]"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how does what you write here follow from what you linked?

Comment: I am currently trying this out and will link to an example on github shortly.

Comment: @4c74356b41 I have added a small pseudo example.

Comment: here I am 2.5 years later using this to get the latest secret version :)

Comment: @4c74356b41 it is now possible to just reference the secret without the version directly and it will retrieve latest. This is officially supported now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references#rotation

Comment: I'm not using it with the app service, need it for something else in the arm template. its not supported there afaik

Comment: is the creation of the secret idempotent?

Comment: can the secret be referenced from within the same arm template as the one creating the secret?

Comment: Yes @AlexGordon but you cannot give the app access to the key vault in the same deployment. 1st deploy- set secret in valut, reference secret in app settings. 2nd deploy- assign accesspolicies to the app and provide "get" access to secrets. If you try to do this in one deploy it will complain about circular dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct, but I didn't want to essentially hardcode the version number into my app settings- which seems to defeat the purpose of having centralized secret management.

To avoid this, instead of using `.secretUriWithVersion`, there is an accompanying property of `.secretUri`

Full usage:

```
"value": "[concat('@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=', reference(resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', variables('keyVaultName'), 'mySecretName'), '2015-06-01').secretUri, ')')]"
```